# Making SharePoint Lookup field multi selection in code with PNP/SP

Tags: javascript, typescript, spfx

I am trying to make a lookup field that will allow multiple selections:

```
ler.list.fields.inBatch(batchCreate).createFieldAsXml(`<Field Name="${strings.Committees}" DisplayName="${strings.Committees}" Type="Lookup" List="{${lookupID}}" ShowField="Title" AllowMultipleVaues="true"/>`);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Type="LookupMulti"` and instead `AllowMultipleVaues="TRUE"` use `Mult="TRUE"`

```
<Field Name="${strings.Committees}" DisplayName="${strings.Committees}" Type="LookupMulti" List="{${lookupID}}" ShowField="Title" Mult="TRUE" />
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/field-element-field

Comment: That did it, thanks!  And thanks for the site, that'll come in handy.